# Commenting code changes behavior of prior code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Guys - I have no idea what is causing my code to break here and I'd love your help to find out why! The function you see below, gets a row from a web service and builds a table row based on the data that is returned.

```
    function GetData(id, thisRow) {
                    if (id == 0) {
                        var tier = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        var currenttier = parseInt(thisRow.find("td.Tier").text());
                        var tier = currenttier + 1;
                    }
    //*** this console.log is affected by the for loop that appears later..
                    console.log(tier);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "F2.svc/GetChildTable",
                        data: id,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {

                            var tempstring = "";
                            var temp = "";
                            if (data.Rows.length > 0) {
                                for (var i = 0; i < data.Rows.length; i++) {
                                    tempstring += "<tr class = 'Show Row ItemID-" + data.Rows[i].ItemID + " ParentID-" + data.Rows[i].ItemParentID + " Tier-" + tier + "'>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='Tier'>";
    //*** the loop below seems to break the tier variable declared up above..             
                                   for (var p = 0; p < tier; p++) {
                                        tempstring += "+";
                                    }
                                    tempstring += " " + tier;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemID'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemID;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemParentID'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemParentID;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemDateEntered'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemDateEntered;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemLastUpdated'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemLastUpdated;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemName'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemName;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemStatusID'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemStatusID;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemTasks'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemTasks;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemBlocks'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemBlocks;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemComments'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemComments;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemFilterID'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemFilterID;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemManHoursEst'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemManHoursEst;
                                    tempstring += "</td>";
                                    tempstring += "<td class='ItemManHoursAct'>";
                                    tempstring += data.Rows[i].ItemManHoursAct;
                                    tempstring += "</td><td></td>"
                                }
                                tempstring += "</tr>";

                                var newRow = $(tempstring);

                                if (id == 0) {
                                    $("table#Main > tbody").html(newRow);
                                }
                                else {
                                    thisRow.after(newRow);
                                    thisRow.addClass("ChildrenLoaded");
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, ex) {
                            var response = xhr.responseText;
                            if (response.length > 11 && response.substr(0, 11) === '{"Message":' &&
                    response.charAt(response.length - 1) === '}') {
                                var exInfo = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                var text = "Message: " + exInfo.Message + "\r\n" +
                                "Exception: " + exInfo.ExceptionType; // + exInfo.StackTrace;
                                alert(text);
                            } else {
                                alert("error");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

[image]

So as you can see, the console.log(tier) displays NaN when it should display 2. What's really weird is that if I comment out the for loop that contains tempstring += "+"; The console.log works as you'd expect. The only relationship I can see, is that the for loop uses p < tier but that shouldn't have any affect on the tier variable declaration earlier on, right?

Oh I guess it also goes without saying that tempstring += " " + tier; is broken too ^^

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lots of code, no HTML dump, but I have a guess.

It seems that it runs fine on the first try, but:

```
var currenttier = parseInt(thisRow.find("td.Tier").text());
```

Kills you afterwards since you add one `+` per tier:

```
console.log(parseInt('++ 1')); // NaN
```

You have to strip the pluses, otherwise your number will not parse.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is actually not in the loop, but in this code:

```
 var currenttier = parseInt(thisRow.find("td.Tier").text());
 var tier = currenttier + 1;
```

What's happening here is that you're parsing "0" the first time, and it works fine, because "0" is an int.

But the second time, you're parsing "+ 1" which does not give a valid int, but NaN. This can be solved by changing the first line to:

```
var currenttier = parseInt(thisRow.find("td.Tier").text().replace(/\D/g, ''));
```

Comment: Thanks, Crast! I really appreciate it.